# How to store more than 8000 characters in a column in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table named as ABC. In this table I have a column which is defined as `XYZ`

```
varchar(8000).
```

In this column I am storing the SOAP error request.

My problem is that now I am getting the length of SOAP Error request more than

```
8000 (to be accurate it is now 16000).
```

I have read that the maximum length of `varchar` is 8000, so my question is that how can I increase the length of my column XYZ to 16000?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you really need more than 8000 characters, you need to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` which can store up to 2 GB of text:

```
XYZ varchar(max)
```

This gives you up to 2 billion characters - which is Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* about 200 times over - should be enough for most cases!

Note: if you get a SOAP request, that most likely will be properly formatted XML - right? In that case, you could also use the `XML` datatype of SQL Server **2005** and newer. It also stores up to 2 GB of data, but it stores it more efficiently than a plain `varchar(max)` does - and you can run XPath/XQuery against it to grab bits from it.

So I'd recommend you use:

```
XYZ XML
```

Comment: hi ... its  not working still shows  error .. "String or binary data would be truncated."

Comment: @Himanshu.Parkash: with just this, I cannot possibly help you - sorry - ask a complete question, with the relevant code, table structures and the complete error message

Comment: @marc_s on a related topic, can nvarchar(max) store more that 4000 chars?

Comment: @Hemant.Gupta: `nvarchar(max)` can store **up to 2 GB** of data - since each Unicode character takes up 2 bytes, that comes out to roughly 1 **billion** characters

Answer (score 4):

Use `varchar(max)`

`varchar(n)` is variable-length, non-Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).

The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting by using a data type that handles long text. "Text" comes to my mind.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, but that is still 2005 he talks about.

Comment: And that note of mine **applies** to **2005** and newer!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend "text". It is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

use text datatype,for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189574(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) - as of SQL Server **2005** and newer, you should **NOT** use `TEXT` anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
--Check this example...
create table t1( i varchar(max))
create table t2( i varchar(8000))

DECLARE @String1 VARCHAR(MAX)
set @String1 = 'Hello'
declare @i int
set @i = 1
while ( @i < 50000)
begin
    set @String1 = @String1 + 'world'
    set @i = @i +1 
end
    select len(@String1)
insert into t1 select @String1 -- will succeed
insert into t2 select @String1 -- will fail 

SELECT LEN(i) from t1
SELECT LEN(i) from t2
```